# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: while running junit in docker compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, junit, amazon-dynamodb, docker-compose

I am testing my app with docker-compose which consist of DynamoDB as an inner container.docker-compose file as below:

```
version: '2'
services:
  appName:
    mem_limit: 1024m
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile.test
      context: .
    ports:
        - "8090:8090"
    env_file:
        - env/test.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - dynamodb
      - memcached
    entrypoint: "./bin/entrypoint.sh"

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.6-alpine"

  dynamodb:
    image: "tutum/dynamodb:latest"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    hostname: dynamodb

  memcached:
   image: "memcached:alpine"
```

On building up the code i am getting following error:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory does not implement the requested interface org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165) org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304) org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611) org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446) org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863) org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57) com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:837) com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
>
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376) com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338) com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287) com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2000) com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1970) com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.getItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1329) com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:433) com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:496) com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:400)

Answer (score 0):

The fix required to get it working is changing the hostname of dynamodb from dynamodb to http://dynamodb, In docker file